# OPTIONS net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I try to deploy a React/Node project on my server.
The app is displayed in my browser BUT when i make an axios request (clicking on "inscription" for exemple) i have a TIME OUT error from the server

in my middleware :

```
axios.post('https://www.mySite.top:3000/inscription', data)
```

server.js :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://www.mySite.top');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  next();
});
...
app.post("/inscription", (req, res) => {
...
```

console error :
OPTIONS https://www.mySite.top:3000/inscription net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score 0):

Try with this configuration :

```
  //add the port config 
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://www.mySite.top:3000');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
```

Also check if the server is up or not.

Comment: Thk Souffanda. Port is already configured at 3000. i tried your solution but doesn't work.
in first of all, i've this error :
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
maybe there's a link with my problem...

Comment: https://www.mySite.top:3000/inscription is not working could you plz share with us your server configuration?

Comment: sorry, my question was generic. Here is the address : www.babylog.top

Comment: you shoud allow this domaine :
```
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://www.babylog.top');
```

Comment: I made what you suggest to me and others things but no way, it doesn’t work. I’ll study the web hoster’s doc, and see the chair/keyboard interface which is probably the problem. Thank you again.